# Найти массив чисел по их XOR

Tags: python, логика, теория

Необходимо найти массив чисел (не больше 10^5 элементов, каждый из которых больше 0, но меньше 2^50). При этом XOR всех чисел этого массива равен X. Хочу увидеть или код (на python) или теорию по созданию такого алгоритма

Comment: Массив из двух элементов: 0 и X. При их перексоривании вы получите X, как и требуется. Не благодарите.

Comment: Немного исправил условие. Подозреваю, что такое решение слишком лёгкое

Comment: Сейчас вы еще раз исправите условие, но массив из 2n + 1 элементов, в котором 1 элемент - X, остальные - одинаковые и больше нуля.

Comment: @Mike вы правы.

Comment: @Mike, возможно, стоит оформить это как ответ.

Comment: @Mike, как обычно - это не наши проблемы :)

Comment: @mike Оформи как ответ. Всё нормально, подходит. Дальше я сам попробую допилить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для операции XOR верны следующие утверждения: пусть `X=A xor B`, тогда `A=X xor B` и `B=X xor A`. так же `X=X xor 0`, `X xor X=0`. В связи с таким ее поведением для нахождения массива длины N нам достаточно сгенерировать N-1 случайных элементов, вычислить их xor (пусть это будет "A", `A=M[1] xor M[2] ... xor M[N-1]`). Если `A=X` то последний элемент пришлось бы сделать 0, но он запрещен, поэтому получим `A=A xor M[N-1]` (уберем влияние N-1 элемента), изменим M[N-1] на любое другое число, заново получим `A=A xor M[N-1]`. Вычислим последний элемент массива `M[N]=A xor X`.